# ionic app script not reloaded after going back

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

In my ionic app when script included in `index.html` is loaded for the first time but after coming back to same screen script is not running.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title></title>
        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script>alert(1)</script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="starter"> 
<ion-nav-view> </ion-nav-view>
    </body>
</html>
```

**homepage.html**

```
  <ion-view>
 <ion-nav-bar align-title="center" class=" bar-royal">
     <ion-nav-title>
  <span>Find Hotels</span>
 </ion-nav-title>
  </ion-nav-bar >
<ion-content  padding="true">
alerted 1 on initial load but not after moving back to same page
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that Ionic chaches the views, so controllers are called only on app start or when you disable the caching.

You can listen to the $ionicView.enter event and insert in the callback function  the code that you need to execute every time the view is active.

```
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function (e) {
  //insert here the code to execute every time the page is active
});
```

Comment: I am using ` $ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);` and cache is set to false in ion-view. I am actually using google map api so how can i enter it in `$ionicView.enter`